# Array copy exclude each x element

Tags: java, android, arrays, rgb, rgba

I am converting an RGBA image to RGB. Using naive array copy:

```
for (int j=0, i=0; i<argbBytes.length; i++){
    if (i%4 < 3) {
        thumbRGB888[j++] = argbBytes[i];
    }
}
```

But, as expected, it is ultra slow (in comparison to System.arraycopy() method), especially on an Android device. Is there a trick to do it faster?

Comment: u can try i+4 or something else instead of i++

Comment: @Manmohan I'm bypassing only one cell.

Comment: System.arraycopy() and then set every 4th element to 0 should give the same results but maybe faster?

Comment: @neurite I finally want to create a smaller array - to drop the 'a' channel.

Comment: What about using a custom [Iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) that would skip the alpha value ?

Comment: Mark, the code you posted here does not imply a smaller array. E.g. when i is 3, it is skipped and argbByte[3] is left untouched.

Comment: @neurite argbByte is the old array.

Comment: @bvidal Iterator is much more costfull, isn't it?

Comment: @Mark I didn't test the `Iterator` and I was more looking for an elegant way to do it rather than an effective way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use two indexes and `System.arraycopy()`, copying 3 elements each time:

```
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < argbBytes.length; i += 4, j += 3)
{
    System.arraycopy(argbBytes, i, thumbRGB888, j, 3);
}
```

Should be significantly faster. Not only does it get rid of the modulo and comparison, `System.arraycopy()` is implemented with native code, relying on `memcpy` which is going to be faster than individual assignments.

Comment: Just out of curiousity, I run your code in C#, of course, I change `System.arraycopy` to `Array.Copy`. Then the time is two time longer than the original(6091ms compares to 3021ms). Maybe the implementation of `Array.Copy` in C# is different than `System.arraycopy` in Java. Am I wrong?

Comment: Quite frankly, C# has nothing to do with Java so I'm confused as to what that has to do with anything. As noted above, yes, this is implemented in native code in the JVM and is significantly faster than coping elements one-by-one.

Comment: Yes! 45ms versus 80ms

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
if (i%4 < 3)
```

do

```
for (int j=0, i=0; i<argbBytes.length; i++){
   thumbRGB888[j++] = argbBytes[i++];
   thumbRGB888[j++] = argbBytes[i++];
   thumbRGB888[j++] = argbBytes[i++];
}
```

This solution is far faster, because modulo operation and compare are more costfull.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid the `if` statement, it does 2 operations.
Start with i=0, i%4<3 means: 0,1,2, 4,5,6, 8,9,10.
Here's how I'd do:

```
int div = 4;
int n = argbBytes.length - argbBytes.length%div;
int i=0;
int j=0;

for (; i<n; i+=div){
    // i = 0, 4, 8 ... then i, i+1,i+2 should pass (i%4<3)  
    thumbRGB888[j++] = argbBytes[i];
    thumbRGB888[j++] = argbBytes[i+1];
    thumbRGB888[j++] = argbBytes[i+2];
}

for(;i<argbBytes.length;i++){
    //i=n,n+1,n+2, since n%4==0 then (i%4<3) is passed
    thumbRGB888[j++] = argbBytes[i];
}
```

-> increments of `i` are the same
tested with [ 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] return [0,1,2,4,5,6,8,9,10]
test with array of 10,000,000 elements, run in a loop of 30
original code: 3191ms
modified code: 1653ms
I've tested in C# so maybe the result would be different. Btw, it's may not quite much an improvement.

Answer (score 0):

***Not a well defined answer, but a pointer:***
Never done, and not entirely satisfying your request, but leave the conversion to [BitmapFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html). Entirely unsure, but:

Use a BitmapFactory to get an ARGB Bitmap from the bytes. If not mutable, then maybe no new allocation is done. Might also be, that you first need to wrap the bytes into a Buffer.

Then `Bitmap.copy` should be possible or so.

Some wild ideas:

```
BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opts.inMutable = true; // Bitmap generated mutable.
opts.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888; // I hope not BGRA.
Bitmap bmARGB = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(argbBytes, 0, argbBytes.length,
    opts);

bmARGB.setHasAlpha(false);

DisplayMetrics display = ...;
int[] colors = null; // Palette
Bitmap bmRGB = bmARBG.createBitmap(display, colors, width, height,
    Bitmap.Config.RGB_565); // 16 bit colors only!
bmARGB.recycle();
```

Comment: AFAIK, BitmapFactory doesn't have RGB888 pix fmt. BTW, I've created the original RGBA using BitmapFactory.